# Assigning values to empty field in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

In my attribute table, I have a field with empty slots. Though, I want to add `Christchurch` to fill all of these empty slots for this one particular column. I have thousands of rows, and wish not to manually include the name. How would I go about this on ArcMap?

I have tried using the field calculator and adding this syntax:

```
Replace(chr('Christchurch'))
```

Though it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [How To: Replace the text in multiple fields in an attribute table using the Field Calculator tool](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012062)

I tried:

```
Replace(["City_link], " ", "Christchurch")
```

Then it worked.

I believe the  `" "` is to allow for `Christchurch` to replace the empty cells.

Comment: (You could also select rows with empty values and Field calculate to `"Christchurch"`)